When I run my Python from Cx_freeze executable It cannot find index.html when it exists (Flask Python)
I'm running this code for developing a web scrapper(project I decided to code myself with some help from chat GTP)
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, 
Response
import os
import re
import logging
import json
import requests
import threading
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed, TimeoutError
import time
import atexit
import sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
MAX_ADDITIONAL_PAGES = 3
MAX_WORKERS = 5
MAX_TIMEOUT = 50  # Maximum time for each search operation in seconds

# Determine base directory
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


# Update paths for bundled application
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except AttributeError:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

# Use OneDrive directory for JSON files
onedrive_base_dir = os.path.expanduser(r"~\OneDrive - The People Group\General - Web Scrapper APP\Final_excrator")

if not os.path.isdir(onedrive_base_dir):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"OneDrive directory not found: {onedrive_base_dir}")

def onedrive_path(filename):
    return os.path.join(onedrive_base_dir, filename)

timer_file = onedrive_path('timer.json')
keywords_file = onedrive_path('keywords.json')
config_file = onedrive_path('config.json')
invalid_keywords_file = onedrive_path('invalid_keywords.json')
search_within_website_file = onedrive_path('search_within_website.json')

stop_thread_event = threading.Event()
output_lines = []
extractor_thread = None


# Function to get OneDrive directory dynamically
def get_onedrive_directory():
    possible_directories = [
        os.getenv('ONEDRIVE_DIRECTORY'),
        os.path.expanduser(r"~\OneDrive - The People Group\Web Scrapper APP - General\Final_excrator\Data"),
        os.path.expanduser(r"~\The People Group\Web Scrapper APP - Final_excrator\Data"),
        os.path.expanduser(r"~\OneDrive - The People Group\Web Scrapper APP - General\Final_excrator\Data"),
        os.path.expanduser(r"~\OneDrive - The People Group\General - Web Scrapper APP\Final_excrator\Data")
    ]

    for directory in possible_directories:
        if directory and os.path.isdir(directory):
            logging.info(f"Found OneDrive directory: {directory}")
            return directory
    logging.error("OneDrive directory not found in any of the specified locations.")
    return None


onedrive_directory = get_onedrive_directory()

# Load configuration from file
def load_config():
    if os.path.exists(config_file):
        with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    return {}

config = load_config()

directories = [onedrive_base_dir]

# Fallback to the current directory if OneDrive directory is not found
if not onedrive_directory:
    logging.warning("OneDrive directory not found, falling back to current directory.")
    onedrive_directory = base_dir






@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start_script():
    global extractor_thread, stop_thread_event
    if extractor_thread and extractor_thread.is_alive():
        return jsonify({'status': 'already running'})
    try:
        stop_thread_event.clear()
        extractor_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_extractor)
        extractor_thread.start()
        return jsonify({'status': 'started'})
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Failed to start extractor: {e}')
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': str(e)})


@app.route('/stop', methods=['POST'])
def stop_script():
    global stop_thread_event
    if extractor_thread and extractor_thread.is_alive():
        stop_thread_event.set()
        extractor_thread.join()  # Wait for the thread to finish
        logging.info('Extractor stopped')
        output_lines.append('Extractor stopped')
        return jsonify({'status': 'stopped'})
    else:
        return jsonify({'status': 'not running'})


@app.route('/log_stream')
def log_stream():
    def generate():
        global output_lines
        while True:
            if output_lines:
                yield f"data: {output_lines.pop(0)}\n\n"
            time.sleep(1)

    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')


@app.route('/get_timer', methods=['GET'])
def get_timer_route():
    return jsonify({'RUN_INTERVAL': get_timer()})


@app.route('/set_timer', methods=['POST'])
def set_timer_route():
    timer_value = request.json.get('RUN_INTERVAL', 300)
    set_timer(timer_value)
    return jsonify({'status': 'timer updated'})


@app.route('/get_keywords', methods=['GET'])
def get_keywords_route():
    keywords = get_keywords()
    logging.info(f"Keywords fetched: {keywords}")  # Add logging
    return jsonify(keywords)


@app.route('/update_keywords', methods=['POST'])
def update_keywords_route():
    new_keywords = request.json.get('keywords', [])
    set_keywords(new_keywords)
    logging.info(f"Keywords updated: {new_keywords}")  # Add logging
    return jsonify({'status': 'keywords updated'})


@app.route('/get_invalid_keywords', methods=['GET'])
def get_invalid_keywords_route():
    invalid_keywords = get_invalid_keywords()
    logging.info(f"Invalid Keywords fetched: {invalid_keywords}")  # Add logging
    return jsonify(invalid_keywords)


@app.route('/update_invalid_keywords', methods=['POST'])
def update_invalid_keywords_route():
    new_invalid_keywords = request.json.get('invalid_keywords', [])
    set_invalid_keywords(new_invalid_keywords)
    logging.info(f"Invalid Keywords updated: {new_invalid_keywords}")  # Add logging
    return jsonify({'status': 'invalid keywords updated'})


@app.route('/get_search_terms', methods=['GET'])
def get_search_terms_route():
    search_terms = get_search_within_terms()
    logging.info(f"Search Terms fetched: {search_terms}")  # Add logging
    return jsonify(search_terms)


@app.route('/update_search_terms', methods=['POST'])
def update_search_terms_route():
    new_search_terms = request.json.get('search_terms', [])
    set_search_terms(new_search_terms)
    logging.info(f"Search Terms updated: {new_search_terms}")  # Add logging
    return jsonify({'status': 'search terms updated'})


@app.route('/directory', methods=['POST'])
def open_directory():
    directory_path = None
    for dir in directories:
        if os.path.isdir(dir):
            directory_path = dir
            break

    if directory_path:
        try:
            os.startfile(directory_path)
            return jsonify({'status': 'directory opened'})
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'Failed to open directory: {e}')
            return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': str(e)})
    else:
        message = 'Directory does not exist in any of the specified locations.'
        logging.error(message)
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': message})


@app.route('/source_file', methods=['POST'])
def open_source_file():
    input_filename = "report1718353090095_full.xlsx"
    file_path = None

    for directory in directories:
        potential_path = os.path.join(directory, input_filename)
        logging.debug(f"Checking path for source file: {potential_path}")
        if os.path.isfile(potential_path):
            file_path = potential_path
            break

    if file_path:
        try:
            os.startfile(file_path)
            return jsonify({'status': 'source file opened'})
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'Failed to open source file: {e}')
            return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': str(e)})
    else:
        message = 'Source file does not exist in any of the specified directories.'
        logging.error(message)
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': message})

I have put my index.html within templates folder and when I run it from Pycharm everything works as intended, however when I try to run it from another PC using the exe file made from CX_freeze addon it cannot find the index HTML.
I get this error:
TemplateNotFound
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
I have tried multiple solutions from chat_GTP and my assumption is that the problem consists that the entire project is located on ONEdrive. Any help would be welcomed.`

There are some things that you need to look out for.

CX_ freeze configuration: modify your setup.py or the setup file that you have to include the template directory explicitly. To do that you need to add the include files parameter to specify additional files.
Path: make sure that you have added the path to your pc. By going to settings, system, about, advanced system settings, environmental variables, system variables, PATH, edit and then add the new path which is the path to the cx_freeze if I'm not mistaken.

